# show a quotient group is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let a and b be nonzero integers. Let $\sigma:\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sigma((x,y))=ax+by.$ Suppose $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Show that $(\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z})/\langle(a,b)\rangle$ is cyclic.

It would be great if anyone can let me know what I should do to prove it.

Thanks

Comment: Well, the standard way to show that a group is cyclic is to exhibit an element $g$ such that every element of the group is a power (or a multiple if you note additively) of $g$. What could $g$ be here?

Comment: @fkraiem  Yes, I am aware of that. I am just having trouble with all things together. I do not have trouble with cyclic group and quotient group separately, but when they are combined, I often get confused.

Answer (score 1):

Or I'm misunderstanding something, or something's missing in the question...or the question is completely trivial: we have that

$$\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/\langle (a,b)\rangle \cong H\le \Bbb Z$$

But $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is cyclic and thus **also** $\;H\le \Bbb Z\;$ is cyclic...

**Added on request:** Since  g.c.d.$\,(a,b)=1\;$ then there exist $\;m,n\in\Bbb Z\;$ s.t. $\;ma+nb=1\;$ , and thus

$$\sigma (m,n)=ma+nb=1\implies \text{Im}\,\sigma=\Bbb Z$$

Comment: Thanks, this is the second question. The 1st one is the show that σ is a group homo.

Comment: I see, @Singularity_2045 .

Comment: Can you let me know what is H?

Comment: I guess the difficulty lies in showing that the kernel is exactly what you think it is.

Comment: @Singularity_2045 Did you try some easy examples? Say, with $\;a=1\,,\,\,b=2\;$ and the like?

Comment: I think the given $\sigma$ has kernel not $\langle(a,b)\rangle$ but $\langle(b,-a)\rangle$.

Comment: The question is not completely trivial and the condition about $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is essential because for example $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/\langle (2,2) \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}$ which is definitely not cyclic.

Comment: @AnuragA, as it was posed it is trivial since $\;\sigma\;$ is defined a homomorphis towards $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , which a cyclic group. In your example there is no homomorphism with that kernel towards $\;\Bbb Z\;$ but rather towards $\;\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z\;$ , which is *not* cyclic.